# apt, disable signature expiry checks

Tags: apt

I am trying to use apt with a repo that hasn't been touched in a long time. Unfortunately the gpg key for said repo is expired (I tried updating it from a variety of keyservers, no luck)

I would rather not disable signature checking completely, is there any way to tell apt to verify signatures against expired keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that there is no way to disable this check in apt, the code that implements the check is the following in methods/gpgv.cc.

```
if (strncmp(buffer, GNUPGKEYEXPIRED, sizeof(GNUPGKEYEXPIRED)-1) == 0)
{
   if (Debug == true)
      std::clog << "Got KEYEXPIRED! " << std::endl;
   WorthlessSigners.push_back(string(buffer+sizeof(GNUPGPREFIX)));
}
```

And it doesn't seem to be be behind any form of conditional.

However the check can be worked around by using faketime. e.g.

```
faketime 2017-01-01 apt-get update
```